# Removing the last character from a string

Tags: java, string

I am having trouble with a recent Java project. I am attempting to just the String "white" from the String. No matter what method I attempt, the last "_" always remains.

```
    String questionText = "The white house is _white_";
    String correctResponse = questionText.replace(questionText.substring(0, questionText.indexOf("_")+1), "");
    correctResponse.substring(0,correctResponse.length()-1);
    System.out.println(correctResponse);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string you want is always between underscores (or at least after one underscore), you could just split the string and take the substring at index 1:

```
String correctResponse = questionText.split("_")[1];
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Warning: This solution would fail should underscore appear _more_ than twice in the string.  It would fail for this string: `The _big_ white house is _white_`.  The regex answer is probably the safest bet here.

Comment: In that case, this would work: `String[] stringPieces = questionText.split("_"); String correctResponse = stringPieces[stringPieces.length-1];`

Answer (score 2):

`substring` don't modify original object.

use

```
 correctResponse = correctResponse.substring(0, correctResponse.length() - 1);
```

Comment: just like how you use `String correctResponse = questionText.replace(questionText.substring(0, questionText.indexOf("_")+1), "");`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to group everything between underscores, and then `String.replaceAll(String, String)` to actually remove everything but the group. Like,

```
String correctResponse = questionText.replaceAll(".+\\s+_(.+)_", "$1"); // white
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lastIndexOf`

```
String correctResponse = questionText.replace(questionText.substring(questionText.indexOf("_"), questionText.lastIndexOf("_")+1), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You think to complicated - why do you need replace? You can achieve the same with substring

First statement

```
String correctResponse = questionText.substring(questionText.indexOf("_")+1)
// ==> correctResponse = "white_"
```

Second statement

```
correctResponse = correctResponse.substring(0, correctResponse.indexOf("_"))
// ==> correctResponse = "white"
```

As @neuo pointed out, substring won't change the string..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change line 3.

Original Line :
correctResponse.substring(0,correctResponse.length()-1);

Correct Line :
correctResponse = correctResponse.substring(0,correctResponse.length()-1);

Answer (score 0):

If you use a regular expression you don't have to check index bounaries.

```
String string = "Merry Christmas!".replaceAll(".$", "");
System.out.println(string);
```

will print out

```
Merry Christmas
```